# Are Browser URL encoded XSS Attacks vulnerable?

Tags: javascript, xss, url-encoding, owasp, burp

I am using Burp Tool and Firefox .

This is the attack .

```
http://localhost/xssWebsite/?aParameter=<script>alert('XSS');</script>
```

I perform this attack in two ways.

- Using Burp Suite repeater Tool .

  GET /xssWebsite/?aParameter=`<script>alert('XSS');</script>`

  Other http headers are included.

  The **Response** fetched included `<script>alert('XSS');</script>`
- When i tried to accomplish the same using Firefox.

  Firefox encodes the URL before sending the request , Hence **Response** also contains encoded script which is not executed.

Can we use tools like burp to exploit this type of xss attack ?

Comment: How would you get a javascript engine to parse the response body if burp sent the request?

Comment: So these kind of attacks are not vulnerable right .

Answer (score 0):

Your version of firefox is encoding the request, but what about older versions or other browsers? The bottom line is that if you have found XSS, it doesn't matter how it can be exploited, it just needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

newer browsers have already encoded the URL, even if you have disabled XSS-filter, those ""s are still encoded.

In order to do POC of your findings like popping up an alert box, you can use older browsers.

you can also use IETester, and use IE6 tab to simulate. Please note alert box may not be working in IEtester, you can use "confirm" instead

Answer (score 0):

Use a proxy tool like Burp Suite and change the parameters by intercepting the request.